# Как обратиться к имени Combobox как к переменной

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день.
На форме есть n-ое количество ComboBox, имя соответственно:

```
comboBox1
comboBox2
...
comboBox100
```

Можно ли через цикл заполнить их `SelectedIndex` через цикл? 
Или только путем прописывания каждого вручную ?

Comment: ...что у вас за проект? WinForms, WPF?

Comment: Прошу прощения, WPF

Comment: Если бы у вас было MVVM, такого вопроса вообще не возникло бы

Comment: можно, другой вопрос - нужно ли. Судя по всему привязку данных вы не используете?

Comment: если ваш проект еще не слишком большой, то советую переписать под `MVVM`

Comment: данные получаю из таблицы, но, каждому Combobox соответствует не поле в строке, а наоборот. Т.е. таблица, в ней 40 записей, поля соответственно конечная часть `comboBox` и поле с его значением.

Comment: ...из описания ничего не понятно

Comment: не уверен, что правильно вас понял, вы отображаете таблицу в виде `DataGrid`, `ListView`, ...?Можем продолжить обсуждение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)? мне кажется так решить проблему можно будет быстрее

Comment: Вам не должно этого хотеться, точно так же как вы не хотите получать доступ к переменным по строковому имени. Расскажите, какую задачу вы решаете, скорее всего у вас неверный подход к ней.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но как описали в комментариях: желательно такие вещи делать по мввм. 
Для того, чтобы перебрать все элементы, используйте панели компоновки (StackPanel, Grid etc.). У них есть свойство Children, возвращающее коллекцию UIElement"ов, содержащихся в панели. Можно перебрать через обычный foreach

Comment: как к ним обратиться через `foreach`, я не могу найти пример как обращаться к имени компоненты по динамически собранному имени.

Comment: вот вы пишите в XAML 
`<StackPanel x:Name="RootPanel"> тут комбобоксы <SP/>`


В код бихайнде пишите 


`foreach(var item in RootPanel.Children) { (item as ComboBox)?.SelectedIndex = что-то }`